# Rails app instances & memory usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Is the memory usage for number of Rails app instances linear?

I have a rails app on heroku that normally runs on a a couple dynos with 2 app instances per. We've been offered a free month of a Performance-L dyno so I've been playing around with the web concurrency a little bit.

I noticed that initially moving from 2 to 4 seemed to double the memory usage. But as I continued to increase the app instances, the increase in memory slowed. Currently I have 40 app instances running on this 14GB machine and am only using about 6GB. Is it simply a matter of not enough traffic for them all to be initialized?

What else is at play here and what are my limitations to how many instances I can run on this Performance-L Dyno?

Comment: **The wind direction and the faze of the stars**. Jokes aside there are so many factors that can influence memory usage so that any answer is purely speculative.

Comment: In general, yes. But I'd imagine there is some insight regarding the relation of app instance concurrency to RAM usage.

Comment: Yes but this question is probaly not a good fit for the stackoverflow Q&A format as it can not be answered in an authoritative way.  stackoverflow is not the place for "I about to do A, any tips?" type questions. You are welcome to ask them on the chat though.